# How to resize an aspect ratio of an image to be in a limit

Tags: python, image, resize

I have a homework of basic Python, and can't do anything with it. I need to write a program where you give two numbers (a,b) which are 2 sides of an imaghe, then it computes and changes both sides' size to be in the given limit (2 Mp, 2*1024*1024), keeping the aspect ratio. This is what I've done so far:

```
a = int(input("a= "))
b = int(input("b= "))
hanyados = float(a/b)
if a * b <= 2*1024*1024:
    print ("we dont have to change anything")
else:
    while a * b > 2 * 1024 * 1024:
        --algorithm of resizing here--
    print (a)
    print (b)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since a/b is hanyados, a = b * hanyados, and a * b = b * b * hanyados = 2Mp.
so b * b = 2Mp / hanyados,  or b = sqrt(2Mp/ hanyados). And then determine a from above (a = b * hanyados). That's the logic, you can write the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I managed to write my code with this!